# How to set default value to field with CsvHelper ClassMap when the header is not present?

Tags: csvhelper

I'm wondering if there is a way to set default value to a field even when the header column is not present. I know I can set the default when it's specify but I would like to set to Sex to an enum value Sex.Unknown when the Sex column name is not specified.

```
File example 1 :
Id, Name, Sex
1, Name 1, Male
2, Name 2, Female
```

---

```
File example 2 :
Id, Name
1, Name 1
2, Name 2
```

---

```
  Public NotInheritable Class CustomLineModelClassMap
    Inherits ClassMap(Of LineModel)

    Public Sub New()
        Map(Function(m) m.Id)
        Map(Function(m) m.Name)

        Map(Function(m) m.Sex).Optional().Name("Sex").Default(Sex.Unknown).TypeConverter(Of CustomEnumerationConverter(Of Sex))
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

This may not be ideal, but appears to work for me as long as Sex is the last item.

```vb
csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = Nothing
```